# How to do multiple pagination using PEAR Pager class

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, pear

I am using [PEAR Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) class for paging. The page is developed using bootstrap and uses tabs for displaying content. I want to use paging in each of the tabs.  I am checking the URL urlVar parameter to change the active state of the tabs. The problem is that the urlVar parameter gets appended to the URL. So when the pager link in the second tab is clicked first tab urlVar plus the second tab urlVar  is passed to the URL and both the tabs gets activated. How can I remove the urlVar of the first tab when the second tab pager link is clicked and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different variable for each pager.

See [the options](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.pager.factory.php):

> urlVar [string]
>
> Name of URL var used to indicate the page number. Default value is "pageID".

To omit the page variables of other pagers, use

> excludeVars [array]

Comment: I have used different variable for urlVar. But all the variables will get appended to the url. So all the tabs will get activated. I have solved the problem by using ajax as given in the tutorial http://www.alberton.info/pear_pager_tutorial_javascript_navigation.html#.U70CM7Hs1dI